# Golang: removing Modification Instructions from Output in Golang Text Processing

Tags: go

I'm working on a Golang program that receive as arguments the name of a file containing a text that needs some modifications (the input) and the name of the file the modified text should be placed in (the output). the modification that program should execute is when in the output appear (low, ) it turns the previously specified number of words in lowercase

(Ex: "This is SO EXCITING (up, 2)" -> "This is so exciting")

the program is working but i can't remove (up, 2) from the output file can some one please help me.

This is the code.

```
func LowModification(text string) string {
// Split the input into words
words := strings.Fields(text)

for i, word := range words {
    // Split the word on comma (",") to check for modification instructions
    parts := strings.Split(word, ",")
    if len(parts) == 2 {
        instruction := strings.TrimSpace(parts[0])
        value := strings.TrimSpace(parts[1])

        if instruction == "(low" {
            //fmt.Println("Entered")
            // Convert value to an integer
            if num, err := strconv.Atoi(value); err == nil {
                // Convert the last "num" words to lowercase
                for j := len(words) - 1; j >= i && num > 0; j-- {
                    words[j] = strings.ToLower(words[j])
                    num--
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        value := strings.TrimSuffix(word, "(low)")
        words[i] = strings.ToLower(value)
    }
}

// Join the modified words back into a string with spaces
return strings.Join(words, " ")}
```

Thanks..!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing due to two issues; your code is not checking for "up" (as per the example you give; the code is looking for "low") and "(up, 2)" contains a space (so will be split by the first `strings.Fields`). Adding extra output should help you find the issue (or improve the question) - [try this](https://go.dev/play/p/YvAb67Vgs6z).

Answer (score 0):

And for removing the instruction I think a regexp would do the work, see https://golangbyexample.com/regex-replace-string-golang/amp/
First create a regexp that matches the (up, number) then replace it with an empty string